# Can I update a single file of Laravel project when it's hosted and live?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel application. It's hosted and people are using it. Actually it's live now. But there's a little issue on images. Some images are not displayed correctly. So I need to fix that. Only some HTML parts and it's done by Blade templating engine. I have access to server and I can edit that files online and fix that issue.

Is that can be a problem ? Do we need to compile or something like that ?

Comment: You can edit that file. No issue

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe Thanks bro

Comment: What is wrong with the images? Are the URLs incorrect in the HTML? Do the images no longer exist? Do you have permission issues with the images that prevent them from being displayed publicly?

Comment: @ArmanH The only issue is the size and the images ratio. Not looking so good. Ratio is so bad and some images so stretchy. So need to change some CSS

Comment: Modifying the CSS should have nothing to do with Laravel or PHP, so you can easily modify the files you want and re-upload them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can edit that file. But make sure you have take a proper backup of the code on your local system and after updating the file on server update your local copy of that code as well.

And after update run the following command through terminal:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This command remove the existing cache and the changes are reflected immediately.